Python - Clear and Print to Same Line for Multiple Lines on Command Prompt
I want to clear and update the same lines on command prompt for each file it processes with Python.
First I tried using ANSI codes using sys.stdout.write('\033[F\033[F\033[F') and sys.stdout.write('\033[K\033[K\033[K'), but this doesn't seem to work for command prompt and each string printed to a new line instead of the same line.
I then tried using something like this:
def update_progress(action, processed, total, mode):
    percent_complete = (processed / total) * 100
    lines = [
        f"{action}",
        f"{processed} of {total} items {mode}.",
        f"{percent_complete:.2f}% complete."
    ]
   for line in lines:
      # Clear the line by overwriting with spaces and then return to the start of the line
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + ' ' * shutil.get_terminal_size().columns + '\r')
        sys.stdout.write(line + '\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()

This gave me the same result but an extra blank line between each line it was printing the string.
I want to also try to have the script work for Windows cmd.exe and LibreELEC (Linux) terminal.

The "command prompt" as it comes in a fresh windows install is a 45+ year old program that has not seem updates in the last 30. Install the "windows terminal" program (it allows you to execute cmd, the shell, not the "terminal emulator") all the same, and works out of the box with text attribute and flow ANSI codes.

@jsbueno Downloaded Windows Terminal to find it most certainly can handle ANSI escape codes with the script doing exactly how I wanted it to work.

Nice. I´ve promoted the comment above to a proper answer, since it worked, and added some more info. Best regards.

The "command prompt" as it comes in a fresh windows install is a 45+ year old program that has not seem updates in the last 30. Install the "Windows Terminal" program (it allows you to execute cmd, the shell, not the "terminal emulator") all the same, and works out of the box with text attribute and flow ANSI codes.
But if you need this in order to be able to distribute your program to others, changes to your system won´t help -
you may find that a practical - probably the simplest - way to have an uniform behavior from the terminal, is to use the now classic 3rd party package "colorarama". It will require a from colorama import init; init() to enable the ANSI codes even on old cmd.
(It has some drawbacks, though: newer terminal programs accept ANSI codes for setting RGB color, for example, instead of a fixed palette of 16. Colorama can´t do those, and will swallow the ANSI codes for RGB color setting, for example)
